# Click in a specific element of list of web elements in Java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests

I am automating a web page using cucumber and selenium in java, and I have this xpath

```
      .//*[@id='chosen_motivos_investimentos_chosen']/div[1]/ul[1]
```

and inside the ul[1] I have a bunch of li, in this case I have this portion of html:

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">LA - Media Buying Fees ‐ Traditional</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">LL - Marketing Development</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">LQ - Media Buying Fees ‐ Digital</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">LU - Media Costs ‐ Traditional</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">LV - Advertising Production Costs ‐ Traditional</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to click in a specific li to select, this specific is given via parameter (String despesa), I have tried this:

```
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='chosen_motivos_investimentos_chosen']/a"))).click();
    List<WebElement> dropDespesa = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='chosen_motivos_investimentos_chosen']/div[1]/ul[1]"));
    i = dropDespesa.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        WebElement row = i.next();
        if(row.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(despesa)){
            System.out.println("Igual");
            row.click();
        }
        System.out.println(row.getText());
    }
```

But webdriver never goes inside if, and I already debugged and made sure that despesa is in fact equals row.getText()

Comment: Are elements loaded dynamically? Are you sure that `dropDespesa` is not empty?

Comment: dropDespesa is not empty I already tried to iterate without the if, and it prints all elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just locate the desired `li` by text and click it:

```
// open up the dropdown
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cho‌​sen_motivos_investimentos_chosen']/a"))).click();

WebElement dropDespesa = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='chosen_motivos_investimentos_chosen']/div[1]/ul[1]"));

dropDespesa.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[. = '" + despesa + "']")).click();
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but webdriver wont locate the element because <li> is inside a dropdown list, and they will only be visible when I click in the list, which I do like this: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='chosen_motivos_investimentos_chosen']/a"))).click();

Comment: @Rogger it should work, updated including your opening the dropdown part. Check it out.

Comment: It did not work because despesa is the exact text between tags <li></li>
For instance, I can pass despesa as "LA - Media Buying Fees ‐ Traditional"

Comment: @Rogger that's exactly what the XPath is checking - the exact text of `li` to match `despesa` value. What error did you get? Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, I was using another variable, it worked, thanks :)

Comment: @Rogger glad to help!